How do I filter data to only include Item Numbers where there is a negative value present in Projected Quantity column?
I need to only return rows that have Item Number 67, as there is negative Projected Quantity values here. I need to return all rows with Item Number 67, not just rows with a negative Projected Quantity value.
If an extra column needs to added to insert a formula that's no problem. I have looked at advanced filter options and cannot see how this can be done.
Any help is really appreciated.



Start Date
Item Number
Projected Quantity




05/12/2024
45
51866


06/12/2024
45
51866


09/12/2024
45
51241


10/12/2024
45
51235


19/12/2024
45
51235


19/11/2024
67
1000


19/11/2024
67
500


20/11/2024
67
-250


21/11/2024
67
-500


15/11/2024
111
404


25/11/2024
111
550


26/11/2024
111
2470


27/11/2024
111
5678




Try using INDEX()+AGGREGATE() functions here:


• Formula used in cell E2
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$14,
 AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($B$2:$B$14)-ROW($B$2)+1)/
 (COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14,$B$2:$B$14,$C$2:$C$14,"<0")>0),
 ROWS(E$2:E2))),"")


Formula needs to copy down and copy right.

Another alternative method:
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$14,
 AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$14)/
 ($B$2:$B$14=AGGREGATE(15,6,IF($C$2:$C$14<0,$B$2:$B$14,1/0),1)),ROW($A1)),
 COLUMN(A$1)),"")



=DROP(REDUCE("", UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B14, C2:C14 < 0)),
 LAMBDA(a, v, VSTACK(a, FILTER(A2:C14, B2:B14 = v)))), 1)


